# index.html file doesn't show style when directly accessed through browser

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

So, I've been noticing when I want to check my designs directly by clicking on the index.html file, it just won't show the style:

[image]

But if I check it out through VS Code then it will show up

[image]

This is my html head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>BMI careers</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/img/logo.png">

  </head>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the paths relative paths, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>BMI careers</title>
<!-- just add a '.' in front of the path -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="./img/logo.png">

  </head>
```

This is because the / means the root in your computer and ./ means current folder in which this file exist.

It works in vs code because you are running it on a local server and the root (the '/') is the root of the server **not** the root of your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Try taking the first "/" away from the roots.
what i mean is, instead of this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

write this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

in all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ./css/style.css and ./css/bootstrap.min.css rather than just a /